# Python .split(), Can you split in multiple ways in the same string?

Tags: python, string

If i have a text file such as:

```
"1,2,3,4,5 1 2 3 4 5
1
2
3
4
5"
```

How do i account for all of these different ways my numbers are separated if I am appending them to the same list?

Comment: `s.replace(',',' ').split()`

Comment: Regex split https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split

Comment: numbers = line.replace(","," ","\n").split()
returns 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Additionally this has to be done without importing any modules.

Comment: No where in that line of code are the characters of that string being interpreted as integers. You should see [ask] and post about the actual code you’re having issues with

Comment: the last post was directed at dirck's suggestions of s.replace(',',' ').split() as a solution; however i added the \n character

Comment: `.replace(","," ","\n")` isn't valid.  Third argument would be max count and you're passing a string.  split with no arguments handles the end of line.